# Windows CMD showing encrypted strings weirdly

Tags: ruby, encryption, cmd

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env ruby

require 'digest'
require 'digest/bubblebabble'
require 'base64'
require 'colored'

def sha256(info)
  Digest::SHA256.digest "#{info}"
end

def sha256_hex(info)
  Digest::SHA256.hexdigest "#{info}"
end

def sha256_base64(info)
  Digest::SHA256.base64digest "#{info}"
end

def md5(info)
  encrypt = Digest::MD5.new
  encrypt << "#{info}"
  encrypt.hexdigest
end

def bubblebabble(info)
  Digest::SHA256.bubblebabble "#{info}"
end

def base64(info)
  Base64.encode64("#{info}")
end

def start_encryption
  puts "Choices include:",
       "1. SHA256",
       "2. SHA256 HEX",
       "3. SHA256 BASE64",
       "4. MD5",
       "5. SHA256 BUBBLEBABBLE",
       "6. BASE64"
  print "\nWhat would you like to encrypt to: "     
  input = gets.chomp.to_i
  case
  when 1
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    sha = sha256(input)
    puts "\n#{sha}".green.bold
  when 2
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    sha_hex = sha256_hex(input)
    puts "\n#{sha_hex}"
  when 3
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    sha_64 = sha256_base64(input)
    puts "\n#{sha_64}".green.bold
  when 4
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    md5_encrypt = md5(input)
    puts "\n#{md5_encrypt}".green.bold
  when 5
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    babble = bubblebabble(input)
    puts "\n#{babble}".green.bold
  when 6
    print "Enter string: "
    input = gets.chomp
    base64_encrypt = base64(input)
    puts "\n#{base64_encrypt}".green.bold
  end
end

start_encryption
```

Basic encryption tool. However when trying to encrypt for some reason in the CMD on windows 8 it shows up like this:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why it's doing this? Is there a certain encoding I need to play with?

Comment: `?` means the character isn't in the font.

Comment: Raw hashes are binary representations; they will likely not print cleanly (Which is why they are often base64'd/hexed as you are doing elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with a minor change to your code:

```
input = gets.chomp.to_i
  case
  when 1
```

Should instead be

```
input = gets.chomp.to_i
  case input
  when 1
```

Enter string: America

088f003833d523d9dccc529e929afdc7